# SpriteKit background moving at the same speed as a sprite using PhysicsWorld

Tags: sprite-kit, physics

Hey guys so my first solution to centering the sprite with the background moving with it was a combination of using the physic's world engine in SpriteKit and using the update function.

The problem with that is I'm pretty sure the update function does not sync with the physics world because my main sprite keeps flickering between frames and then centers itself.

Is there a way to center the movement of a sprite and a moving background with just the physics world engine? I need the engine because I need the gravity and the impulses for my game.

Comment: are you checking on simulator or actual device

Comment: Thanks for the question. Yeah I'm testing on a device. I usually do.

Comment: try to change physics related properties inside         -(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    
}

Comment: Thats perfect I was able to move my centering function to both the update and did simulate and it did the trick go ahead and put your comment as the answer and I will check it. THANKS again!